# Merge unversioned directory structure into SVN repository

Tags: svn, unix

I committed a 3rd party project into my own svn repository. Now, I got a new version of that project and I'd like to substitute it in my repository.

The project is quite big (1.2GB) and the new version has new files/directories and also deleted files/directories.

The trivial solution is

```
svn rm project
mv /path/to/new/project .
svn add project
svn ci
```

However, I loose the history for everything. Additionally, the svn server won't be able to use delta-compression (Yes, server space does matter).

Another way is to just overwrite all files in the working directory and then commit it. However, the deleted files remain in the repository. `svn add --force *` also "forgot" to add some files.

**What are the other possibilities to commit the new version?** Is this an unusual use-case so there is no built-in support for this? 
(With Tortoise SVN I'd mess around with the `.svn` folders, Tortoise offers to delete missing files/folders in the commit dialog, but the command line version refuses to commit if it encounters files/folders not deleted using `svn rm`)

**Extra 1**: How to avoid changes in my repository to be overridden? (There only few, so re-applying is acceptable at the moment)

**Extra 2**: I replaced all symlinks with copies of the destination (To get rid of `special status changed` errors). How to avoid this?

**Extra 3**: How to cope with renamed files/directories? Since I just get the new version without change history, it is impossible to determine those automatically. `svn mv` before committing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fs2svn tool, part of [svn2svn](http://svn2svn.codeplex.com/) does the basics of what you're looking for. Start with [this post](http://code.dblock.org/ShowPost.aspx?id=135).

Comment: Thank you! However, meanwhile I switched to `git` which allows such kind of update (`git -A`)

Comment: The svn2svn is specifically for windows (the OP is asking for a tool on unix).

Answer (score 1):

You might try the method that subverion reccomends for merging in vendor code via a vendor branch then trunk merge.  They've also got a tool, svn_load_dirs.pl, to help with additions, removals, and moves in the upstream version.

Details can be found at:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html